# Appium/wdio - unable to dismiss location permissions alert on Android

Tags: android, cordova, appium, hybrid-mobile-app, webdriver-io

I'm using [webdriver.io](https://webdriver.io/) to write a suite of [Appium](http://appium.io/) tests for a hybrid [Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/) App.

```
"appium": "^1.10.0",
"wdio-appium-service": "^0.2.3",
"wdio-jasmine-framework": "^0.3.8",
"webdriverio": "^4.14.1",
```

**In one of my tests** I am trying to programmatically **accept** the **Location Permissions native modal** presented on App launch on top of the WebView.

I can easily do so in iOS using [browser.alertAccept()](http://v4.webdriver.io/v4.12/api/protocol/alertAccept.html) but the latter does not seem to work for Android.

I also tried to switch to the native context to dismiss it but had no luck.

```
function dismissLocationPermissions() {
  if (browser.isAndroid) {
    new WebView().switchToContext(0);
    browser.pause(2000);
    const ANDROID_ACCEPT_ALERT_SELECTOR = "//*[@class='android.widget.Button'][2]";
    // OR '*//android.widget.Button[@text="ALLOW"]' ?
    $(ANDROID_ACCEPT_ALERT_SELECTOR).click();
    WebView().switchToContext(1);
  } else {
    browser.alertAccept();
  }
}
```

How can I dismiss the native alert on Android using wdio?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The permission dialog is native, so you don't need to switch to the webview to dismiss it.
2. There is an android `id` associated with the allow/deny permission button, so you can use that instead of the identifier you have used.

The `id` for `allow` button is: `com.android.packageinstaller:id/permission_allow_button` .
The `id` for `deny` button is: `com.android.packageinstaller:id/permission_deny_button`

Comment: 1 - It's the other way around, the application runs in a webview so I need to switch to the native layer. 2 - can't seem to make it work :(

Comment: I got it working correctly switching to the right context (I had to pass 0 as argument for the native one) and using this selector: `"//android.widget.Button[@resource-id='com.android.packageinstaller:id/permission_allow_button']"`. Thx

Comment: Android Q brings up a new ID for this one: `com.android.permissioncontroller:id/permission_allow_foreground_only_button`

Answer (score 3):

There is `autoGrantPermissions` [DesiredCapability](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/DesiredCapabilities), if you set it to `true` - Appium will automatically determine which permissions are required by your application and grant them to the application during the installation procedure.

The capability is set to `false` by default so you need to explicitly set it like:

```
DesiredCapabilities dc = new DesiredCapabilities();
dc.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.NO_RESET, false);
dc.setCapability(AndroidMobileCapabilityType.AUTO_GRANT_PERMISSIONS, true);
driver = new AndroidDriver<>(url, dc);
```

More information:

- [Appium Desired Capabilities](http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/caps/)
- [Application Setup](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TC/Application+Setup)

Comment: I don't want to auto grant permissions, I need to test all the permissions flow. Thx anyway